# Event handler function as a method

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I am very new to OOP and attempting my first project with it. Here is my question:

```
var calculator = {
  operationBar: document.getElementById('operation-bar'),
  print: function(){
    this.operationBar.innerHTML += 1;
  }
}

var one = document.getElementById('number1');
one.addEventListener('click',calculator.print)
```

When I click on my HTML element with the id (number1) I get the following error:

Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined.

It is not relating the *this* keyword to my calculator object.

However if I do this:

```
var calculator = {
  operationBar: document.getElementById('operation-bar'),
  print: function(num){
    this.operationBar.innerHTML += 1;
  }
}

calculator.print()
```

It works and the *this* keyword seems to be working correctly.

The reason I know the problem is with the *this* keyword is because if I perform the function in the first snippet and replace `this` with `calculator` then it will work, as my event handler function as well.

Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: you can try `bind`

Comment: Do `one.addEventListener('click',function(){calculator.print()})` or `one.addEventListener('click',calculator.print.bind(calculator))`

Comment: Remember, in DOM event handlers like onclick `this` is the DOM element receiving the event

Comment: Ok thanks all, reading through it now.